# How to bind only to the base of a Path?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Let's assume I have this binding:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyBaseProperty.MySubProperty}" />
```

Is it possible to tell WPF to listen to changes to `MyBaseProperty`? And whenever `MyBaseProperty` changes to (re-)query `MySubProperty` of `MyBaseProperty`?

The background behind this question is: I have a view model that contains a property (`MyBaseProperty`) pointing to an instance of a class that does not implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. The `DataContext` for this `TextBlock` however does implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and can therefore inform the view about changes to `MyBaseProperty`.

If would be great if you found to accomplish this kind of base-with-path-binding a way where I can get around ValueConverters and extending my ViewModel with `INotifyPropertyChanged`-backed Property wrappers for `MySubProperty`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with creating a wrapper for `MySubProperty` in my view model. This wrapper is defined as something like this:

```
public string MySubProperty
{
    get
    {
        return MyBaseProperty.MySubProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        MyBaseProperty.MySubProperty = value;
        FirePropertyChangedEvent("MySubProperty");
    }
}
```

I further added a call to `FirePropertyChangedEvent("MySubProperty");` to the `MyBaseProperty` setter:

```
private MyBasePropertyType _myBaseProperty;

public MyBasePropertyType MyBaseProperty
{
    get
    {
        return _myBaseProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        _myBaseProperty = value;
        FirePropertyChangedEvent("MyBaseProperty");
        FirePropertyChangedEvent("MySubProperty"); // also inform about changes to MySubProperty
    }
}
```

Finally, I changed my view to use the view model's `MySubProperty` wrapper:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding MySubProperty}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This would probably fix it for you,

You can listen to MyBaseProperty Changed event and when that happens ..

You can force binding updates like this --

```
BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase(_myTextBox, TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This does not really feel clean because it would require me to pollute the view's codebehind. Not really what I'm looking for...